# Is ZIP archive capable of storing permissions?

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, compression

I am using Maven Assembly plugin to bundle my application along with configuration/settings files. It allows to specify persmissions to be stored along with files, which is quite convenient.

Still I never found a confirmation, that ZIP archive is capable of storing UNIX permissions. Is it? (please, post some proof if you answer either yes or no).

Comment: Surely this is easy to test yourself, create your deployment then erm deploy it in a lab and see what happens.

Comment: I am always glad to proof something doing an experiment, but what I was looking for is a link to some standart or specification, CLEARLY STATING if it is possible or not.

Comment: Why don't _you_ read the zip specification then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the unzip(1) manpage:

```
   Dates,  times  and  permissions  of stored directories are not restored
   except under Unix. (On Windows NT and successors,  timestamps  are  now
   restored.)
```

So yes, permissions can be stored.

Comment: Hah! Funnily enough this made life Fun later on: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-archive/issues/53

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

- Create you deployment.
- Transfer it to another machine.
- Deploy the application.
- Compare the permissions on the reference machine with the lab machine.

Profit!